# WebView Scroll will not call Main View Controllers Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, viewcontroller

Ok so I have a webview that is a subview of an opengl view controller.  now on the main view I have an animated background.  When the subview is loaded, the background still animates.  When I scroll the webview,  The viewcontroller no longer animates.  I have done a trace on what is happening and it seems that the viewcontroller is not being updated while the scroll gesture is happening.  I tried handleing this with scrollview delegate and all of its functions but they only handle before and after, not during. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?  Unfortunately I can not provide too much source code because the project is very large,  but I will provide what I can upon request.  Here is how I am making the webview:

```
webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];

webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
if(Settings.networkOnline)
     [[VIEWCONTROLLER view] addSubview:webView]; // add in uiwebview
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some information on how you're doing your animation. Doing an animation with animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: runs fine while scrolling a web view.

Comment: animation is just opengl in the main view rendering the game,  the main issue here is that the main view controllers update is not being called,  its as if the scrolling locks the update